# Understanding the Role of Qiskit's VQE Code in Light of Pre-calculated Zero-Point Vibrational Energy in Gaussian Files

Tags: qiskit, vqe, chemistry

In the context of quantum computational chemistry, the Qiskit VQE (Variational Quantum Eigensolver) code is often used to calculate the vibrational energies of molecules, including the zero-point vibrational energy (ZPE), or ground state vibrational energy. Given that the input for the Qiskit VQE code typically includes a Gaussian file, which already has the ZPE calculated, what is the specific advantage or purpose of using the Qiskit VQE code for this task? Is there an added value or different perspective that the Qiskit approach brings to calculating vibrational energies, considering the Gaussian file provides the same information?"

Reference: [Qiskit Vibrational Structure Tutorial](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/nature/tutorials/02_vibrational_structure.html)